# See date/time of most recent WLAN sync in iTunes

Tags: itunes, data-synchronization, wifi, ios

When syncing via WLAN, the most recent sync date/time is displayed on the iOS device but not on iTunes (where only the time of the last backup is shown which seems to be the time of the most recent cable-based sync). Is there a way to show the most recent WLAN sync as well?

Answer (score 2):

On iTunes select your iDevice from left menu and `Summary` tab on the right pane, under `Backup` section you'll see a sentence like `last backed up to this computer: Today 06:30` this date shows you the most recent sync, whether it was over WiFi or USB.

Here is mine: [image: last sync]

Comment: This is the date of the last *backup*, not the last *sync*.

Comment: @patrix When music/app/podcast etc. changed on a sync operation iTunes backup my iDevices automatically.    `First thing done when you perform a sync is an iPhone backup.` quote from [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2806556?start=0&tstart=0#13339196)

Comment: Well, I just tested it over WiFi, the date is not updated.

Comment: @patrix I'm testing it over WiFi also. But trying with changing something (adding podcast episode, deleting app, adding new contact etc.) to make syncing meaningful.